# How do I add a target to open a new tab from an api image link in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, tabs

My goal is to allow the clicked image to open in a new tab.

```
<li>
<a href="<%= show[:link] %>"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8fNs6Rl3WXCiHqp3OgCPze8YnDi3bKpbMV41oWmDi01hcDtyz9w3xIcdjKFZqGCwhw=w300" alt="songkick" id="songkick" target="_blank">
</a>
</li>
```

but I am not quite sure where the ruby code will be placed and if I need a link_to instead of a href.

Comment: Ok, so the code that I have has the target="_blank" inside the a tag but it is not opening in a new tab, since the api has a ruby link, how would I add the click to open in a new tab without javascript?

Comment: what does the html result looks like (inspect element in chrome is a good way to find this)

Answer (score 0):

A `link_to` in Rails templates is a shortcut for making an `a` to a `route` somewhere else within the app.

it is not necessary that a link use `link_to` and this case is a good one for using a simple `a` tag, since it isn't opening a `route` in the app but just linking to an asset.

Also the `target="_blank"` should be in the `<a>` tag if you want that tag to open a new window

Comment: Ok, so the code that I have has the target="_blank" inside the a tag but it is not opening in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was not putting the target blank attached to the link
the correct code looks like:

```
<li><a href="<%= show[:link] %>" target="_blank"><img src="https:somestuff" alt="songkick" id="songkick"></a></li>
```